# Pushpin with EventToCommand

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, bing-maps

I am trying to adapt the UsingBingMaps sample included in the Windows Phone 7 TrainingKit (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=ca23285f-bab8-47fa-b364-11553e076a9a) to use MVVM-Light toolkit. I am trying to set up a command to the Pushpin's MouseLeftButtonUp event using EventToCommand but the command does not get executed. Below is the code of the pushpin:

```
<my:Pushpin Style="{StaticResource PushpinStyle}"                                        
Location="{Binding Location}"
Background="{Binding TypeName, Converter={StaticResource PushpinTypeBrushConverter}}">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.PushpinClickCommand, ElementName=HomePage}"/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
</my:Pushpin>
```

Am I missing anything? Was anyone able to use EventToCommand with the Pushpin object?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with the command?

I can get a command to fire using this, but i cant seem to get the object details from the arguments passed.

I have used this in silverlight, which I think is directly usable in WP7 (please correct me if I am mistaken)

```
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
              <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=pinSelCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" ></cmd:EventToCommand>
         </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In my viewmodel constructor I have

```
PolySelCommand = new RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>(PolySelCommandExecute);
```

in viewmodel class

```
public RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs> pinSelCommand{ get; set; }
private voidpinSelCommandExecute(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   // < Your code >
}
```

Hope this helps out.  If you work out how to pass the object details, please post back as I have  problem [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042536/mvvm-light-relaycommand-with-pushpins)